# I have a issue with passing by reference using string

Tags: c, string, pass-by-reference

This is the question i am working on.

*"A simple encryption scheme named "rotate13" for encrypting text is to convert each letter  (a…z or A...Z) to another letter by counting forward 13 letters, looping around from 'z' to 'a' or  'Z' back to 'A' if necessary. 
Write a function named rotate13 which takes a single null-terminated string as a parameter 
and converts it to its rotate13 equivalent. The function should modify the string directly, and it 
should not return anything. Remember, only letters should change; all other characters remain 
the same. You may assume that ctype.h is correctly included at the top of your program so 
that you can use any functions within the library if you wish. "*

And this is the error i keep getting

```
"error C2664: 'rotate13' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char (*)[10]' to 'char *[]'"
```

Thanks for the help. It will help me in my revisions for finals.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int rotate13(char *array[]);
int size=10;

int main() 
{

    char arr[10];

    printf("Please enter the  letters you wish to encrypt: ");
    scanf("%s",&arr);

    printf("%s",arr);

    rotate13(&arr);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

int rotate13(char *array[])
{
    int pointer;
    while(*array[pointer]!='\0')
    {
        if(isupper(*array[pointer])!=0)
        {
            if(*array[pointer]<'N')
                *array[pointer]=*array[pointer]+13;
            else
                *array[pointer]=*array[pointer]-13;
        }
        else
        {
            if(*array[pointer]<'n')
                    *array[pointer]=*array[pointer]+13;
            else
                *array[pointer]=*array[pointer]-13;
        }
        pointer++;
    }
    printf("%s", *array);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rotate13(arr);` instead of `rotate13(&arr);` and parameter should be `char []` instead of `char *[]`

`rotate13(&arr);` sends the address of the array to the function which causes the parameter mismatch

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `&` from `scanf("%s",&arr);`

   scanf("%s",arr);
2. `rotate13` is expecting an argument of type `char **` but, by passing `&arr` you are passing it an argument of type `int (*)[10]`. Passing `arr` to `rotate13` will solve your problem.

   `rotate13(arr);`

Comment: Shouldn't the argument of rotate 13 just be char*, so that all the *array[pointer]-stuff can be simplified?

Comment: @Atle; Yes! But then OP must have to remove `*`'s from all the expressions inside `rotate13`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a string as the parameter of `rotate13`, so use either

```
int rotate13(char *array);
```

or

```
int rotate13(char array[]);
```

and pass `arr` like `rotate13(arr)`. the same for `scanf("%s",arr);`

And inside the function `rotate13`, `pointer` is an `int`(bad variable name) that isn't initialized. To access the characters, use `array[pointer]`, not `*arr[pointer]`.

The function should look like this:

```
int rotate13(char array[])
{
    int n;
    while(array[n]!='\0')
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have said, you're better of with `int rotate13(char array[])`. To understand the context, you should read this wonderful page: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/

Basically, passing a pointer to an array is redundant here, because in C when you pass an array to a function, what's actually passed is a pointer to its first element. Arrays are inherently passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Some things need to be explained. `"string" in C` is the address of a character buffer.

Since the identifier `arr` in `char arr[10];` degrades to a pointer to the first element of the array, So you don't need to specify a pointer `(i.e &)` to the `string` in the argument to scanf.

By passing `&arr` in your `scanf` as `scanf("%s",&arr);` the pointer passed to scanf is now a doubly-indirect pointer (it is a pointer to a pointer to the beginning of the buffer) and will likely cause the program to crash or other bad behaviour.

The strings in c, dont require `&array` as they implicitly pass address of the first element of the character array

So your two statments `scanf("%s",&arr)` should be simply `scanf("%s",arr)` and `rotate13(&arr)` should be `rotate13(arr)`. notice that address of the first element are implicitly passed in the function calls.

Your function  `rotate13(char *array[ ])` is completely wrong way of doing it

```
char arr[10] -> can hold single string  ( simply an array )
char *array[] -> can hold multiple strings ( also called array of pointers)
```

the formal parameter should be `rotate13(char array[])` or `rotate13(char *array)`.

After seeing your code I believe your not changing the contents of `arr` so you require a `call by value` instead of a `call by address`

```
char array[] - > call by value , char *array -> call by address
```

Your variable `int pointer` is not initialized before its use, Its dangerous. First initialize is to zero.

Change all the occurences of `*array[pointer]` to `array[pointer]`

If your wishing to change the contents of `arr` use call by address just change `rotate13(char array[])` to `rotate13(char *array)` and Dont forget to initialize pointer variable to zero .